# CoffeeScript Object Property Pointing to the Same Object

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

I have a class which I would like to use for two separate objects. The class has a property *myvar*, which is an object itself. It should be different for each object. However, in all instantiated objects the *myvar* properties point to the same object, see code below. How can I have a unique/private *myvar* property for each object?

```
class Test
  myvar: {}

obj = new Test
obj2 = new Test
obj.myvar['key'] = 'value'

console.log obj.myvar # Result: { key: 'value' } / Correct
console.log obj2.myvar # Result: { key: 'value' } / Incorrect! Expected {}!
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.6.3
(function() {
  var Test, obj, obj2;

  Test = (function() {
    function Test() {}

    Test.prototype.myvar = {};

    return Test;

  })();

  obj = new Test;

  obj2 = new Test;

  obj.myvar['key'] = 'value';

  console.log(obj.myvar);

  console.log(obj2.myvar);

}).call(this);
```

Update. I have found a possible "solution": put all properties that are objects into the constructor, see below. Is there a better solution?

```
class Test
  constructor: ->
    @myvar = {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't a better solution than setting your instance variables in the constructor:

```
class Test
  constructor: ->
    @myvar = {}
```

Anything in the class definition is attached to the prototype so they're shared by all instances just like everything else in the prototype. A quick look at the JavaScript might be helpful:

```
var Test;
Test = (function() {
  function Test() {}
  Test.prototype.myvar = {};
  return Test;
})();
```

You can safely put immutable things (such as strings, numbers, and booleans) in the class definition but not mutable values. For example, this is fine:

```
class C
  s: 'pancakes'
```

because the only way to change `s` is to replace it completely:

```
c = new C
c.s = 'house'
```

and that shadows the prototype value rather than modifying it.

Comment: Thanks! Is this an error in CoffeeScript, e.g. should it be explained better, because I did not find any reference to this in CoffeeScript tutorials.

Comment: Well the docs do say ["assign prototypal properties"](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) while discussing the `class` keyword, it is generally assumed that you know how JavaScript works in the CoffeeScript world so I guess they didn't think it was necessary to explicitly mention.